# how to use apache streaming Excel for large datasets

Tags: apache-poi, streaming

Code i use to configure security for springboot.
Formlogin with custom user details manager.
Also, keep in mind that this custom bean has the responsibility to determine the destination to which the user is directed after logging out. Because of this, pairing the logoutSuccessHandler attribute with logoutSuccessUrl is not going to work, as both cover similar functionality.

###################################

```
 package com.example.demo;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.example.demo.csv.ResultSetHelperService;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class WebController {
    
    @Autowired 
    DataSource ds; 
    


    @GetMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView getHome(HttpServletRequest request,  HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        return new ModelAndView("home");
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/downloadcsv")
    public ResponseEntity<?> downloadFile() throws SQLException, IOException {
        
        // get data 
        ResultSet resultSet = getResultSet(); 
        
        // write to temp file as csv 
        File csvTempFile = writeCsvAsTempFile(resultSet); 
        
        // get temp file as resource 
        Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(csvTempFile); 
        

        String contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        String headerValue = "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"";
         
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, headerValue)
                .body(resource);       
    }
    
    private ResultSet getResultSet() throws SQLException { 
        String sql = "Select * From ems_transaction";
        Statement statement = ds.getConnection().createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
        return resultSet; 
    }
    
    private File writeCsvAsTempFile(final ResultSet rs ) throws IOException { 
        
        String dirPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"); 
        String fileName = System.currentTimeMillis() + ".csv"; 
        File file = new File(dirPath + fileName); 
        System.out.println("File is : " + file.getAbsolutePath());
        
        com.example.demo.csv.CSVWriter writer = new com.example.demo.csv.CSVWriter(file.getAbsolutePath());
        
        try {
            //Define fetch size(default as 30000 rows), higher to be faster performance but takes more memory
            ResultSetHelperService.RESULT_FETCH_SIZE = 30000;
            //Define MAX extract rows, -1 means unlimited.
            ResultSetHelperService.MAX_FETCH_ROWS = -1;
            writer.setAsyncMode(true);
            int result = writer.writeAll(rs, true);
            System.out.println("Number of rows written to temp file : " + result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null; 
        } finally {
            writer.close(); 
        }
        
        return file; 
        
    }
    



    
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/pjfanning/poi-shared-strings supports a more memory efficient version of shared strings that you can use with SXSSF. If you read the README for poi-shared-strings, there is a link to a sample project that includes an SXSSF demo.